# node express: how to find out if status will be 304 given etag

Tags: node.js, express, etag

How can I find out if the response status will be 304 (Not-Modified) because of etag value received inside If-None-Match header? I want to log this information but cannot get it in the node server. Seems express handles this by itself:

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is to log the final status code after the response is sent, you can listen for the `finish` event and then examine `res.statusCode`.  Here's a simple example:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("temp.html", { root: __dirname });
    res.on('finish', () => {
        console.log(`finish event: ${res.statusCode}`);
    });
});

app.listen(80);
```

Running this server and then requesting `/` the first time logs 200, the second time logs 304.

Comment: That's it! Now I can see how long the browser keeps some cached files and fine tune some of them to be kept more time in the cache. I could not do it from the client side, even with serviceworkers.

Answer (score 1):

Express, gets its `express.static()` from the [`serve-static` module](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static).  That module calls the [`send` module](https://github.com/pillarjs/send) from [here](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js#L96) and that module uses the [`fresh` module](https://github.com/jshttp/fresh/blob/master/index.js#L33) from [here](https://github.com/pillarjs/send/blob/master/index.js#L636) which is where it seems to test the eTag [here](https://github.com/jshttp/fresh/blob/master/index.js#L53).

Here's the `fresh()` function:

```
function fresh (reqHeaders, resHeaders) {
  // fields
  var modifiedSince = reqHeaders['if-modified-since']
  var noneMatch = reqHeaders['if-none-match']

  // unconditional request
  if (!modifiedSince && !noneMatch) {
    return false
  }

  // Always return stale when Cache-Control: no-cache
  // to support end-to-end reload requests
  // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.9.4
  var cacheControl = reqHeaders['cache-control']
  if (cacheControl && CACHE_CONTROL_NO_CACHE_REGEXP.test(cacheControl)) {
    return false
  }

  // if-none-match
  if (noneMatch && noneMatch !== '*') {
    var etag = resHeaders['etag']

    if (!etag) {
      return false
    }

    var etagStale = true
    var matches = parseTokenList(noneMatch)
    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
      var match = matches[i]
      if (match === etag || match === 'W/' + etag || 'W/' + match === etag) {
        etagStale = false
        break
      }
    }

    if (etagStale) {
      return false
    }
  }

  // if-modified-since
  if (modifiedSince) {
    var lastModified = resHeaders['last-modified']
    var modifiedStale = !lastModified || !(parseHttpDate(lastModified) <= parseHttpDate(modifiedSince))

    if (modifiedStale) {
      return false
    }
  }

  return true
}
```

To call `fresh()` yourself to get this value on your own, you would have to be able to pass it the exact headers that `serve-static` and then `send` would pass it.  It's probably doable, but you'd have to trace through how `express-static()` and `send()` are setting up the response headers before passing them to `fresh()`.

---

FYI, this begs the question of "why" are you trying to do this?  What problem are you trying to solve?  Perhaps there is a better way to solve the real problem.  As your question stands now, it's a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you've asked a question about your attempted solution to some problem without telling us what the actual problem is.  There may be a better/easier solution to the actual problem.